# Hostname to docker containers mapping?

Tags: windows, docker, networking, dns, containers

When the Apache is installed directly on the host, I add an internal hostname in `"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"` and using virtual host to easily access different projects locally say: `http://foo.test` and `http://bar.test`.

Using the docker container for each project I can access the project by assigning a host port in the `docker-compose` file.

I hope that docker may have some internal tools to achieve access via hostname to containers.

Using a reverse proxy can be a solution as described in these relatively old but brilliant articles.

- https://www.alexecollins.com/developing-with-docker-proxy-container/
- http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

But because I believe this is a very common development requirement, I hope Docker has something builtin to address it.

Comment: You can start an apache or nginx container using the same docker-compose file by accessing your containers using the service names you declared.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I suggested. Use an nginx or apache as reverse proxy talking to the containers via those ports, and from the host, connect to the nginx or apache using hostnames.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I believe you are referring to the way that is explained in the links.

Comment: That's correct. Reverse proxy is pretty common. I am not aware of a built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem is the following. Consider I have container A and B both running a webserver. I simply add a reverse proxy on my local machine which looks at the hostname and then proxies to the respective containers.

But instead of proxying through the hard-coded ip addresses, I proxy through the local ports. So instead of binding both your containers to port 80, bind them to a random local port (e.g., 4041) and proxy over that. That way you decouple the container IP from your host.

My nginx file looks like this then:

```
server {
    server_name example.com # Add <host lan ip> example.com to your /etc/hosts file

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;   # These two lines ensure that the
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";    # a WebSocket is used
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4041/;
    }

<snip>
```

Adding multiple containers then just means you have to edit 1 nginx proxy file, and bind a port to your local machine. No coupling between Docker ip's and your local hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt in answering this question. The question is not about connecting the containers within the docker network, it's about run independent projects from the host using some hostnames instead of local ports. Please see the links.

Comment: Ah. I see your point now. I will change my answer accordingly.